# IE9 Developer Tool Not Open

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

In IE9 I can not open the Developer Tools. Under tools it display as disable and even if i press F12 it did not pop up. Any one face similar situation?

Comment: [Chrome Frame](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10907385/502381)?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960683/why-isnt-my-ie8-developer-tools-working .

If this is not exactly what you are looking for then try this:
http://www.davidtong.me/ie8-developer-tools-wont-open/